# Read whole folder and upload to s3 with pause/resume functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

my ultimate job is to upload multiple files upload concurrently with pause/resume functionality.

i already achieved single file upload (using multipart upload api) with pause/resume.

but i have no idea about how to achieve multiple files upload concurrently.
because all the examples i have seen over internet using for loops to recursively upload multiple files.

But using for loop , gives inability to achieve functionalities pause/resume.

so how to do this ??

NOTE : i am using node js , AWS-SDK for javascript.

Update : my code

```
var read = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/a/file');
var upload = s3Stream.upload({
 "Bucket": "bucket-name",
 "Key": "key-name"
});
upload.maxPartSize(20971520); // 20 MB
upload.concurrentParts(5);
upload.on('part', function (details) {
  console.log(details);
});
upload.on('uploaded', function (details) {
 console.log(details);
});
read.pipe(compress).pipe(upload);
```

i used this npm package [s3-upload-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-upload-stream)

Comment: can you provide some sort of code or pseudo-code, please?

Comment: You said that you `i already achieved single file upload (using multipart upload api) with pause/resume.`, please upload this code so that we can go off that and make it work for multiple cases

Comment: @Deiv  i updated my code here , any idea ??

Comment: @niccord any idea please ??

Comment: The code doesn't show any pausing functionality

Comment: @Deiv upload.pause() will pause the stream and upload.resume() will resume the stream.